# How to find numbers in List with condition?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am novice in writing lambda expressions and I have the next problem:
I have

```
List<int> lifeField;
I want to find index of those members, that correspond to next condition:
(((number % (10 * currentMove)) == 1) || ((number % (10 * currentMove)) == 2))
where number is member of List and currentMove is integer - 0,1,2
```

For example:

```
if it is first move
currentMove = 0
I search number 1 or 2 
if it is second move 
I search numbers 11,21
```

......
I want to find how to write this here with lambda.... or in other function

```
int indexOfLife = Array.FindIndex(lifeField, ?????????);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var indexes = lifeField.Select((x,i) => new {Index = i, Element = x})
    .Where(x => 
        ((x.Element % (10 * currentMove)) == 1) || 
        ((x.Element % (10 * currentMove)) == 2))
    .Select(x => x.Index)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This return me list of all indexes and looks very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`FindIndex` takes a `Predicate` which is an expression that takes an element and returns a `bool`.

So, you want something like this:

```
number => (
  ((number % (10 * currentMove)) == 1)
  ||
  ((number % (10 * currentMove)) == 2)
)
```

Comment: When I try to use this as predicate, it still give me exception.

Answer (score 0):

Note that currentMove cannot be 0, it will cause `DivideByZeroException`

```
  var ints = Enumerable.Range(1,100).ToArray();
  int currentMove = 1;
  var output = ints.Where(number => number % (10 * currentMove) == 1 || (number % (10 * currentMove))==2);
```